# adb push not working

Tags: push, adb, pull

I am having problem with adb push & pull operations.

My pc os:w7
I am able to enter shell by using command-adb shell.
I am getting shell prompt $ as root.
I have the permission to access the folders (rw).
I am able to list folder contents using ls command.
Now the problem is -
I am using command `adb push D:\myfile.apk /system/app/`
I am getting `error:unable to find myfile.apk.`
If i tried to pull any file from the device ,pull is succesful by
showing bytes transfered, but unable to see the pulled file in local
directory.

I am working with avd 4.

Expecting valuable replies...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax for push:`adb push "./Path with whitespace/Music" ./sdcard/music`

This is the correct syntax for installing an APK: `adb install ./path/application_name.apk`

The paths are relative to where you execute the command from